# any way to record a voice and make it sound like a parrot?

Tags: audio-recording, voice, audacity

I am building an app and would like it to sound like a parrot when it "speaks". Any ideas on how to do this? Is there any type of software that can do it, something like audacity? Any special modulation?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question to me... perhaps try http://audio.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there maybe some VST plugins from TC Helicon that could help.

[TC Helicon](http://www.tc-helicon.com/)

These will work in Adobe Audition, Logic, Cubase etc.